# no reconoce el else

Tags: python, condiciones, float

al ingresar un numero tanto sea flotante o entero siempre me dice que es entero no entiendo porque:

```
import cmath
numero= float(input("introduce el numero a evaluar: "))
resultado=cmath.sqrt(numero)
#esta parte final no me sale
if numero!= float:
    print("este numero es entero")
else:
    print("este numero es imaginario")
print(f"el resultado es: {numero} es: {resultado:.4}")
```

Comment: El fallo está en el condicional, has de poner type(numero) != float

Comment: eh, numero recibe un cast a float de algo. ¿Seguro que eso alguna vez no será float?

Comment: la idea es que reconozca y del el mensaje que es flotante o entero previo al dar el resultado

Comment: El problema esta en la validación, intenta usar `if type(numero) is not float`

Comment: Otra opción puede ser `if isinstance(numero, float)`

Comment: estás diciendo `numero = float(**alguna cosa**)`. Eso siempre va a ser float, a menos que lance un `ValueError`, no?

Comment: por qué contestan la pregunta en los comentarios?

Answer (score 2):

La verificación que requires debe ser a tráves de las [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) type o isinstance. Ahora, la respuesta al efecto que estas teniendo en tu programa se debe a:

1. `numero= float(input("introduce el numero a evaluar: "))` La verificación del tipo después de esta instrucción no tiene mucho sentido, el resultado devuelto por la built-in function `float` siempre sera un objeto de tipo float, en caso de no poder ser convertido a un valor flotante, este arrojará una excepción de tipo `ValueError`.
2. `if numero!= float:`. Como se ha explicado anteriormente, si el programa llega hasta esta línea en la ejecución significa que la línea anterior no lanzó una excepción de tipo ValueError y el tipo de la variable numero siempre sera float, sin embargo estas comparando el valor de una variable con el el tipo float, esto claramente siempre va ser falso, lo que tu realmente necesitas es comparar el tipo de la variable, no el valor de la variable como tal.

La solución a este problema puede ser variado, en general estas son algunas formas de comparar que un variable es de tipo float:

`if type(numero) is float:`

`if type(number) == float:`

`if isinstance(number, float):`

Nota que la primera forma y la segunda pueden parecer muy parecidas y marcar las diferencias puede demandar un poco más de conocimiento con respecto a los operadores `is`y `==` en python, ademas de una noción esencial del Singleton Pattern.

Marcando los anteriores aspectos también es importante que consideres todas las ramificaciones de los tipos [numéricos de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), en tu ejemplo la lógica para determinar que es un entero no es del todo acertada, algo más acorde a tu idea inicial seria:

```py
if not isinstance(numero, float):
    print("este numero es entero o un imaginario")
else:
    print("este numero es flotante")
```

Otra forma de expresarlo sería:

```py
if type(numero) in (int, complex):
    print("este numero es entero o un imaginario")
else:
    print("este numero es flotante")
```